# How do I start a branch with the data from a repository that isn't the one I'm using?

Tags: git

Say I'm working in one locally but I want one off of github. I added that repo as a remote, but how do I now grab a branch from it, and make a branch out of it to switch to and work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the you add the remote (say you called it 'github2'), you can fetch data from it :

```
git fetch github2 master
```

and then start a branch from the remote master (say that you want to call it 'master2') :

```
git checkout -b master2 --track github2/master
```

If you want to work on another branch of github2, just replace master with the branch name you want.